# Как реализовать peer to peer в mirror unity?

Tags: unity3d

В unity мультиплеер можно реализовать с помощью фотона, mirror, UNet и т.д. Я выбрал mirror. Кроме того, есть разные способы реализовать мультиплеер: через выделенный сервер, к которому подключаются клиенты, клиент-сервер(хост), к которому подключаются другие клиенты или peer to peer (когда нет сервера: только клиенты обменивающиеся информацией между собой. Нигде не могу найти реализуемо ли peer to peer в mirror и, если реализуемо, то, где про это можно почитать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.